# Further explanation on a basic C# error for redirecting

Tags: c#, asp.net, session, redirect

**Error Message:** Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

**Description:** An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.

**Exception Details:** System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

```
Source Error:

Line 17:         else // Else they will be redirected and given the message below in the label
Line 18:         {
Line 19:             lblSession.Text = "On the previous page, you typed in " + Session["contentOfTextBox"].ToString();
Line 20:         }
Line 21:     }

Source File: c:\Users\Ryan\Desktop\asppub\MIS3200\Unit6\RingU6L1_2.aspx.cs    Line: 19
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: "please increase my reputation if you're willing to support a new user!" - that's not the way things work. People will (or at least should) vote on your *content*, not on your newness. As for "there will not be any bad questions asked from my account" - you've given an error message but not given us enough context in terms of code...

Answer (score 1):

You have to check if `Session` exists before using it. You are calling ToString on `Session["contentOfTextBox"]` which is probably `null`. Because either session does not exists or expired.

```
if( Session["contentOfTextBox"] != null)
    lblSession.Text = "On the previous page, you typed in " + Session["contentOfTextBox"].ToString();
```

Comment: Thank you @Adil 
I really appreciate it. I knew it was probably something basic. 
Is there a reason I received a thumbs down? I've heard this website is very helpful but very harsh. How can I do better?

Comment: Read the comment of John Skeet, he told you whats wrong in your question.